# Updating row withing select depending on result of union select

Tags: mysql

I have a table called "scores" with following info:

```
| id | name  | datetime_added      | option |
+----+-------+---------------------+--------+
| 1  | all   | 2023-01-01 00:10:04 | none   |
+----+-------+---------------------+--------+
| 2  | James | 2023-01-01 00:32:18 | none   |
+----+-------+---------------------+--------+
| 3  | all   | 2023-01-01 02:08:51 | none   |
+----+-------+---------------------+--------+
| 4  | all   | 2023-01-01 04:13:07 | none   |
+----+-------+---------------------+--------+
| 5  | Rubio | 2023-01-01 07:05:55 | none   |
+----+-------+---------------------+--------+
| 6  | all   | 2023-01-01 09:17:27 | none   |
+----+-------+---------------------+--------+
| 7  | James | 2023-01-01 10:43:01 | none   |
+----+-------+---------------------+--------+
```

For output I need to add option "some" to the newest entry of "Rubio" where option is "none" if there is any. If there isn't (either name "Rubio" or option "none") then I need to add the option "some" to the newest entry of "all".

What I have done so far? I need to get that table sorted in two ways:

1. By name, "Rubio" needs to be first and "all" needs to be second (names can change and there can be more of them, so alphabetical is not helpful here but 1 name out of all needs to come first, then all and rest ignored).
2. By datetime_added (ID is auto increment so sorting by id should do the trick)

I can manage this by doing:

```
(SELECT * FROM scores WHERE name = "Rubio" AND option = "none" ORDER BY id DESC)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM scores WHERE name = "all" AND option = "none" ORDER BY id DESC);
```

This giving me necessary list of:

```
| id | name  | datetime_added      | option |
+----+-------+---------------------+--------+
| 5  | Rubio | 2023-01-01 07:05:55 | none   |
+----+-------+---------------------+--------+
| 1  | all   | 2023-01-01 00:10:04 | none   |
+----+-------+---------------------+--------+
| 3  | all   | 2023-01-01 02:08:51 | none   |
+----+-------+---------------------+--------+
| 4  | all   | 2023-01-01 04:13:07 | none   |
+----+-------+---------------------+--------+
| 6  | all   | 2023-01-01 09:17:27 | none   |
+----+-------+---------------------+--------+
```

How could I update the table within this one query now when I know I need to:

```
UPDATE scores SET option = "some" WHERE id = 5;
```

This request is also run up to once per second, is this efficient?

Comment: for what are you union the rows with all, when you only want to update the row with rubio?

Comment: As stated I can only update the row with "Rubio" in case there is a correct row with "Rubio", else we will use "all".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For output I need to add option "some" to the newest entry of "Rubio"
> where option is "none" if there is any. If there isn't (either name
> "Rubio" or option "none") then I need to add the option "some" to the
> newest entry of "all".

This can be done by a case statement in the order by clause ,

```
 order by case 
            when name='Rubio' and `option`='none' then 1 
            when name ='all' and `option`='none' then 2 
            else 3 end  asc, datetime_added desc ) row_num
```

Use row_number window function to give update the value

```
WITH ToUpdate AS (
   select id,
          row_number() over( order by case when name='Rubio' and `option`='none' then 1 
                                           when name ='all' and `option`='none' then 2 
                                           else 3 end  asc,datetime_added desc ) row_num
  from scores
  where `option`='none' 
  and name in ('all','Rubio')
)   
UPDATE scores  
INNER JOIN  ToUpdate  ON scores.id = ToUpdate.id
SET  `option` = 'some' 
WHERE ToUpdate.row_num = 1;
```

Above query will update only if `name='Rubio' and` option`='none'` or `name ='all' and` option`='none'` otherwise would do nothing because other records are filtered in the where condition `where` option`='none' and name in ('all','Rubio')`

[See example](https://dbfiddle.uk/xkEwyam-)

**Edit**

> How efficient do you think this method is? Considering I would need to
> run that query around twice per second on peak times against a table
> with more than 100 000 rows?

To speed up the query add the following index

```
alter table scores add index opt_nam_id(`option`,name,id);
```

[See example](https://dbfiddle.uk/P6Tuhwnk)

I cant be sure how fast the query would be on your environment, please make the suggested changes and let me know.

Comment: This seems to work as expected, thank you! How efficient do you think this method is? Considering I would need to run that query around twice per second on peak times against a table with more than 100 000 rows?

Comment: @Ajama I can't be sure about the performance. See the updated part and add the suggested index on the table

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `UNION`, use `LEFT JOIN`. Then you can use `IFNULL()` to provide one selection as a default if the other selection isn't found.

```
UPDATE scores AS s
JOIN (
  SELECT IFNULL(t1.id, t2.id) AS id
  FROM (SELECT id
        FROM scores
        WHERE name = 'Rubio' AND `option` = 'none'
        ORDER BY id DESC
        LIMIT 1) AS t1
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT id
        FROM scores
        WHERE name = 'all' AND `option` = 'none'
        ORDER BY id DESC
        LIMIT 1) AS t2 ON 1 = 1
) AS x ON s.id = x.id
SET s.option = 'some'
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qXF8t94Pgu5ZAzc5KiG4ac/0)

Comment: If you remove Rubio from the table this will fail updating the *If there isn't (either name "Rubio" or option "none") then I need to add the option "some" to the newest entry of "all"*